# Create an Array of arrays of arrays of different shapes

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, jagged-arrays

I am trying to create an array of 6 arrays each containing 4 arrays, each of those 4 arrays with different shape.
Like in the form below:

```
[[array([[1,2,3,4,6,5],
         [5,6,6,7,7,5],
         [6,6,5,5,6,5],
         [4,6,6,7,7,5],
         [5,6,6,7,7,5],
         [6,6,5,5,6,5],
         [6,6,5,5,6,5],]),
 array([[9,9,9],
        [9,9,9],
        [6,6,6],
        [3,3,6],
        [6,6,6]]), 
array([[6],
       [7],
       [7],
       [7],
       [7]]),
array([[7,8,8,8,8]])], 

[[array([[1,2,3,4,6,5],
         [5,6,6,7,7,5],
         [6,6,5,5,6,5],
         [4,6,6,7,7,5],
         [5,6,6,7,7,5],
         [6,6,5,5,6,5],
         [6,6,5,5,6,5],]),
 array([[9,9,9],
        [9,9,9],
        [6,6,6],
        [3,3,6],
        [6,6,6]]), 
array([[6],
       [7],
       [7],
       [7],
       [7]]),
array([[7,8,8,8,8]])]]

..........
```

I have this code but I am doing something wrong, I do not get the desired shape.

Can somebody please help me with this?

```
            int populationSize = 6;
            double[][][][] population = new double[populationSize][][][];
            int value = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
            {
                population[i] = new double[4][][];
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    const int rows = 7, cols = 6;
                    population[i][j] = new double[rows][];

                    for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
                    {
                        population[i][j][k] = new double[cols];
                        for (int m = 0; m < cols; m++)
                        {
                            population[i][j][k][m] = value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Use breakpoints in debugger and step-forward (F10 in VisualStudio) and try to pinpoint where exactly this exception occurs, because you have a lot of arrays.

Comment: Didn't test it, but maybe the error is at `population[j][j] = new double[5][];` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const int rows = 7, cols = 6;
population[j][j] = new double[5][];

for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
```

you are using the same indexes for `population[j][j]`, that is probably incorrect.
You are also specifying 7 rows, but create a matrix of size 5. That is probably incorrect.

As Scopperloit points out, you probably want:

```
const int rows = 7, cols = 6;
population[i][j] = new double[rows][];

for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
```

Overall when debugging problems. Run the code in a debugger and inspect the values against your expectations. Index out of range exceptions are usually very easy to debug:

1. What is the index?
2. What is the length of the array?
3. Is the index or array length incorrect?

Comment: I corrected the errors but the resulting arrays are not in the desired shape

Comment: You specify that you want the array form 6 -> 4 -> 4 -> different shapes, so perhaps you're missing an order of arrays, or you want `rows = 4` instead of `rows = 7`?

Comment: @paul phoenix You are defining you arrays with sizes [6][4][7][6]. If you want to have different sizes for different sub-arrays you have to write code for that. There is nothing in your example to create differently sized arrays depending on the index.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem.
THis function creates an array of arrays of arrays of different shapes according to another array, and fills it with random normal standard distribution values :

```
int[,] netshape = new int[,] { { 3, 4}, { 4, 5}, { 4, 1 }, { 1, 4} }; // The shape of the network
    public double[][][][] CreateNetwork(int[,] netshape,int populationSize )
    {
        normal = new MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal(0, 1);// Generate random normal standard distribution          
        int rows, cols ;
        double[][][][] population = new double[populationSize][][][];
        for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
        {
            population[i] = new double[4][][];
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                rows = netshape[j, 0];
                cols = netshape[j, 1];
                population[i][j] = new double[rows][];
                for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
                {
                    population[i][j][k] = new double[cols];
                    for (int m = 0; m < cols; m++)
                    {
                        population[i][j][k][m] = normal.Sample(); ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return population;
    }
```